# How to get max() to return variable names instead of contents of the variables in R?

Tags: r, max, frequency

From the following table, I have a frequency table, and while I am able to find the maximum, I would prefer to have the "name" of the variable instead, *so 6 would be the answer, instead of 8*.

```
x <- c(1,3,6,7,2,6,7,8,8,5,1,2,3,9,5,4,1,8,3,4,3,6,8,5,8,7,4,6,6,6,6,6)  

t <- table(x)
## x
## 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
## 3 2 4 3 3 8 3 5 1 

max(t)
## [1] 8
```

I know there is a `which.max()` function; however, the code I am trying to implement involves an '**n**' number of variables, so I will be unable to write out each variable name each time the code is run.

Comment: Try `names(which.max(t))`

Comment: @akrun this works, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `which.max` to return the index of the first max value and use that to get the `names`

```
names(which.max(t))
```

If there are ties for `max` value, create a logical `vector` with `==`, get all the position index with `which` and extract the `names`

```
names(which(t == max(t)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to calculate mode i.e most frequent value in a vector.

We can use the function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8189441)

```
Mode <- function(x) {
   ux <- unique(x)
   ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}

Mode(x)
#[1] 6
```